# What should I do to protect my uploaded firebase document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-security

How can I protect my uploaded document in Firebase?

For Example, this is my uploaded document URL:- https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sapient-logic-368311.appspot.com/o/coder.JPEG?alt=media&token=55d1a727-956f-434b-bdad-a08b8ef133d0

Anyone can able to access and see my uploaded document by using this document URL.

How can I protect the uploaded document, then only authorized persons can access the uploaded document.

I want If anyone get document URL although Can't be access or see document

I want like this If anyone try to access my document using document URL:-
[image]

**Or Can I make private bucket in Firebase ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `rules` in it which help you who can read or write the data.

Comment: Can you please share rule for this ? Can Rule help for protecting uploaded URL view authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone can able to access and see my uploaded document by using this document URL.

That's correct. And this is happening because you have shared the entire URL along with the token, which is not correct since the token should act as a security measure to restrict access only to those who possess the token.

So the best option that you have, would be to store such a URL in a database like [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and only allow access for reading the URL using security rules.

Remember, that token is created automatically whenever a file is uploaded to Cloud Storage for Firebase. So don't share that token with anyone.

Comment: But I've pass this url to front-end via API response , so anyone can able to access this URL from network tab . But I want no one can access my uploaded data url

Comment: If you want nobody to be able to read that URL from Storage, then you have to set the security rules for reading in storage to `false`.

Comment: I've set this rule `rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I mean nobody can access document except me Mean authentic user

Comment: In that case, you need to make sure that the authenticated user is the same as the one that reads the data. Have you tried the solution in my answer?

Comment: Check my above comment I've sent my rule

Comment: Those rules deny all reads and all writes.

Comment: But although everyone can access

Comment: Yes, but only if they have the token. The token provides the security you're looking for. Besides that, you secure [Cloud Storage together with Firestore](https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/09/announcing-cross-service-security-rules). Check that out. So give it a try and tel me if it works.

Comment: Can I help you with other information? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

If a specific file is thought to be private, then no client normally should have access to the URL token.

If the case is the file URL was public and you want to make it private, you can modify the access token without being obligated to re-upload the file or changing its path.

I don't know what platform you are working on, but from the Python SDK, it can be done this way:

```
from firebase_admin import storage
from uuid import uuid4

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob(path_to_file)
token = str(uuid4()) # Random ID

blob.metadata = {
        "firebaseStorageDownloadTokens": token
    }
blob.patch() # Updates changes
```

After this, the previous URL will be unusable and firestore will respond with the error you mention:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied."
  }
}
```

**Note that this solution applies for full-stack applications, where backend is what uploads the file to the Firebase Storage. If your project consists of the client connecting directly to the Firebase Storage, then you should take a read about the security rules and use them as a pseudo-backend.**

Comment: Yehh It's work but when I upload any document in firebase with random Token , But If anyone knows full URL with Token then easily able to see or download uploaded document , Then Is It possible except me nobody able to download or see my document ?

Comment: @BhavyaArdeshana Yes. As I said if a file is meant to be private, the token should be as well. Otherwise, you should edit the `rules` file, and write the rules so only authorized connections can access specific files or paths, but this solution seem pretty complex for what you are looking for.